# Android: Remaking an existing project from scratch

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, google-play

There is an existing Android project published in the App Store that I would like to remake from scratch as the previous developer did a horrible job developing said project. Now, I just have a few questions:

• Can I still use the previous Keystore that was used in the old app?

• Can I still use the company domain(com.example.company.appname) in this new project and upload this in the same app in Google Play?

• Any other repercussions that I should take note of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes you can use the same keystore to publish multiple app
- You can't publish app with the same package name. Package name should be unique.
- But you can use the same applicationId/packageName to publish your own version in the same playstore page.

Comment: I would just like to upload the new apk to the same App Page in Google Play. Will that be possible?

Comment: Yes, you can upload using the original application id (package name) as long as the keystore used is the same as for the original upload.

Comment: What if I use a different applicationId/packageName? Will that be rejected?

Comment: If you mean uploading a different package name on the old app store page; that is not possible, once you upload an app with different package name that is considered as new app.